# Use imported static functions to build a c++ class

Tags: c++, class, dll, import

I imported a dll file named swedll64.dll in main function of a c++ program
how can i build a class for imported methods?in other word where should i put this codes in class ? Is there another tricks to do so like Dllimport() and extern in c#?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<math.h>
#include<windows.h>

using namespace  std;

typedef double(*_swe_julday)(int, int, int, double, int);
typedef int(*_swe_calc)(double, int, int, double[], char[]);
typedef void(*_swe_revjul)(double, int, int&, int&, int&, double&);

int main()
{
HINSTANCE hInst = LoadLibrary(L"C:\\swedll64.dll");

_swe_julday swe_julday = reinterpret_cast<_swe_julday>(GetProcAddress(hInst, "swe_julday"));
_swe_calc swe_calc = reinterpret_cast<_swe_calc>(GetProcAddress(hInst, "swe_calc"));
_swe_revjul swe_revjul = reinterpret_cast<_swe_revjul>(GetProcAddress(hInst, "swe_revjul"));
return 0;
}
```

I add this simple code below for C#.this is exactly what  i want to do in c++

```
    public class Swisseph
    {
    Swisseph() { }
     ~Swisseph() { }
    [DllImport("swedll64.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, EntryPoint = "swe_julday")]
    private extern static double _swe_julday(int year, int month, int day, double hour, int gregflag);
    public static double swe_julday(int year, int month, int day, double hour)
    {
        return _swe_julday(year, month, day, hour, 1);
    }
    }
```

Comment: Sorry, your question is confusing, what has C# has to do with writing this code? And what way did the Dll get build and expose it's symbols?

Comment: There nothing you can do to put those functions in a class. But you can call those functions from a class if that's what you want to do. Just call them like regular functions.

Comment: I want to call them from a class . Anyway shouldn't put them in a class as static methods in order to call them?

Comment: @Wolf You can call them from a static method if that's what you want to do. You can call them from a regular method if that's what you want to do. You can call them from outside a class if that's what you want to do. They are just functions (strictly they are function pointers), treat them like any other function. But you cannot **put** them in a class, you can **call** them from a class.

Comment: @john this file has about hundred of functions and i don't want to copy thousands of code lines in main() each time i want to use them in my programs.Clearly the question is how can i call them from a separate class file?I don't think the question be so strange

Comment: @JVApen  https://www.astro.com/swisseph/swephprg.htm#_Toc11319060 this is their website

Comment: So it's a C lib, I would recommend `extern "C" { #include "lib.h" }` and use the functions directly

Comment: @JVApen Do you have any examples? or link? thanks.

Comment: @Wolf It's not a strange question, but it's still not clear to me what you want. Seems to me that the class aspect of the question is irrelevant and you're just looking for a convenient method to import these functions without calling GetProcAddress multiple times, is that correct? It's because you talked about *building a class* that I was confused.

Comment: @Wolf Still trying here, one of the problem with answering questions is that we have little idea of the abilities of the person asking thw question. Above you have a bunch of local variables `swe_julday` etc. If you want to make those available outside of the main function, the simple thing to do is make them global variables, put declarations of those global variables in a header file, and then include the header file in the class file where you want to use those functions. Does that answer the question?

Comment: If i were you, and I was using Visual Studio i would import functions using the __declspec(dllimport) compile extension. It really cleans the code up.

Comment: @iZeusify this is exactly what i want to do but i dont know how? i do this in C# but dont know how use it in c++

Comment: @john I add a little C# code to my question . That is what i want .I don't want to directly use imported methods.  I want to use them in a class , use them as private static methods finally return calculations back to user.

Comment: @Wolf Well Zeusify has shown you how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you would import a function using compiler extension which seems to be what you're asking in the comments.

```
extern "C" {
    __declspec(dllimport) long IoCreateDriver
    (
        UNICODE_STRING* driver_name,
        DRIVER_INITIALIZE* initialization_fn
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want to use a C library in c++.

The best way of doing this is by using `extern "C"` as indicated on the [isocpp website](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/mixing-c-and-cpp#include-c-hdrs-nonsystem)

To copy the example:

```
// This is C++ code
extern "C" {
  // Get declaration for f(int i, char c, float x)
  #include "my-C-code.h"
}
int main()
{
   f(7, 'x', 3.14);   // Note: nothing unusual in the call
  // ...
}
```

Off course you need to update this based on your lib needs. Though it allows you to use the functions as free functions like you are used to.